# laravel remove model observer

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, observers

Is there a way to remove a model observer that is added with

```
$model->observe(new ObserverObject)
```

Maybe something like

```
$model->observers['ObserverObject']->remove()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your event name by doing:

```
dd( $model->getEventDispatcher()->getListeners() );
```

And remove it using:

```
$model->getEventDispatcher()->forget($event);
```

Comment: Hello, the getListeners() function doesn't return anything in my case, but the forget methods called with the event as a string works perfectly. any ideas ? My original code is a copy paste from your answer. I just changed $model to use my model instance and finally changed $event to the hardcoded event name, 'eloquent.updated: Profil'

Comment: This doesn't work for me because getListeners() needs a parameter (Laravel 4.2)

Comment: Yes getListeners requires the event name and it will return a list of closures  that are listening to the event

Comment: So for an entire Observer you would call `foreach ($model->getObservableEvents() as $event) $model->getEventDispatcher()->forget("MyAwesomeObserver@$event")`

Comment: For always-up-to-date information you can follow your `Model::observe` call down the chain. This worked for me: `foreach ($model->getObservableEvents() as $event) $model->getEventDispatcher()->forget("eloquent.{$event}: " . get_class($model)); }`

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question, just provides a workaround which may work for him but not for anyone else trying to figure out how to do this if they want to remove one observer only and keep other observers that may be listening on the same event.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.8

I have an AccountObserver, that observers the creating process on my AccountModel:

```
class AccountObserver
{
     public function creating(AccountModel $account)
     {
     ....
     }
}
```

To disable this, first load the event dispatcher (via any eloquent model), then tell it what to forget. This works for any observer method:

```
$eventDispatcher = AccountModel::getEventDispatcher();
$eventDispatcher->forget('eloquent.creating: App\Models\AccountModel');
```

If you want to remember it again:

```
AccountModel::observe(AccountObserver::class);
```

Comment: I'd love to know what the -1 is for. Did this not work? Was there an error? Is this a bad implementation of the code?

Comment: Wouldn't this disable all creating events? What if you had multiple observers that you wanted to keep which needed the creating event?